# Dynamicaly loading data to Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

While i am working on gridview i faced following problems, any help will be appreciated,

1. When I load data to my gridview it loads only first 3 items of the array but there are 18 items to be load. why it doesn't load other 15 items. (Log.i it shows all the 18 items in my LogCat).
2. Since there are only 18 items belongs to the MainCategoryID=1, it should load only 18 grids, but this loads 28 grids(that is because there are 28 items inside responseJson). I want to limit it to 18 grids. (Inside the loaded 28 grids, there are 3 items loaded and there have repeated in couple of places and other grids are empty grids)

PizzaFragment class

```
public class PizzaFragment extends ListFragment implements OnTaskCompleted {

    private TranslateAnimation anim;
    GridView grid;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_grid_main, container, false);

        new PizzaMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), this).execute();


        grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try
        {
            String[] Description = new String[responseJson.length()];
            String[] ImageURL = new String[responseJson.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);
                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1"))
                {
                    Log.i("MainCategoryID ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    ImageURL[i] = object.getString("ImageURL");
                    Log.i("MainCategoryID ", object.getString("Description"));
                    Description[i] = object.getString("Description");

                   CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), Description, ImageURL);
                grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }
        }
            catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

CustomGrid

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] Description;
    private final String[] ImageURL;

    public CustomGrid(Context c, String[] Description, String[] ImageURL) {
        mContext = c;
        this.ImageURL = ImageURL;
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Description.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizza, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(Description[position]);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(ImageURL[position]).into(imageView);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

this is how my screen looks like (this is not the real image but this is how it looks)

[image]

Comment: @jitain sharma Can u help me with how to change it,

Comment: Your initializing the `String[] ImageURL = new String[responseJson.length()];` which is the length of your json response, which is leads to make the 28 grids. 
Secondly, do not initialize your grid adapter inside the AsyncTask onTaskCompleted(), rather do initialize under the onCreateView(), and keep your adapter empty,
while you got the result just call `adapter.add()` or `adapter.addAll()` and when you done call adapter.notifydatasetchanged. You will be all good to go.

Comment: @jitain sharma is it possible for u to make the changes in the code and show.

Comment: @JohnDavid once check the updated answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once check the loop  `onTaskCompleted` method. you are creating instance of the adapter and setting to gridview inside loop i think its wrong after observing and checking your code i found the first issue.

Second the way you are handling Adapter view inflating method for populating row is also wrong and i can say not a proper way...

So once check the below code for the adapter and `onTaskCompleted` method.

```
@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            String[] Description = new String[responseJson.length()];
            String[] ImageURL = new String[responseJson.length()];
            JSONArray jArrayCategoryWise = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);
                if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(object.getString("MainCategoryID"))) {
                    // add to another jsonarray if MainCategoryID == 1
                    jArrayCategoryWise.put(object);
                }
            }

            /******
             * You can also create class with getter setter method for the
             * Description and ImageUrl.Make the arraylist of the class after
             * parsing jsonArray.
             */
            // which will required on more iteration of your json array response
            CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(),
                    jArrayCategoryWise);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Once check the data is coming properly or not.or are you adding anything in between

ADAPTER

```
    public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Context mContext;
    // private final String[] Description;
    // private final String[] ImageURL;
    private JSONArray json;
    private int size = 0;

    public CustomGrid(Context c, JSONArray json) {
        this.context = c;
        this.json = json;
        if (this.json != null)
            size = this.json.length();
        // You can also create class with getter setter method (getter setter
        // for Descriptions and ImageUrl). and pass arraylist of that class

        // this.Description = Description;
        // this.ImageURL = ImageURL;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.json.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.custom_trips_frag_row, parent, false);
            holder.ivImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        JSONObject jObjectRowData = this.json.getJSONObject(position);
        holder.tvHeader.setText(jObjectRowData.getString("Description"));
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(jObjectRowData.getString("ImageURL"))
                .into(holder.ivImage);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvHeader;
        private ImageView ivImage;
    }
}
```

Please check the answer.. hope i gt ur quesion correctly and you gt your answer ... *** Suggestion *** ONCE CHECK THE [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) class pattern for the BaseAdapter.

Comment: this worked and this loads all the 18 items but still it carries empty 10 grids as well.. how to remove those empty 10 grids.

Comment: your last code worked before your update. Ill edit my question and add a screen photo. Im getting those empty grids because responseJson has some items which belongs to MainCategoryID=2

Comment: is his the reason for that String[] ImageURL = new String[responseJson.length()];

Comment: @JohnDavid current code also should work... the issue is with the imageurl.. either image url is not availble for each grid item or image url is dead .. post JSON response or API url thn can figure it out

Comment: it is not the reason, in this view im loading only the items belongs to MainCategoryID=1, those blank items are belongs to MainCategoryID=2. I figured while debugging it.. I need a way to remove the items belong to MainCategoryID=2 from this view. yh this code works too..

Comment: @JohnDavid pls check the udpated answer i hve updated "onTaskCompleted" method

Comment: small problem, when i used jArrayCategoryWise.put(object); as u have mentioned then it gives an error saying The constructor CustomGrid(FragmentActivity, JSONArray) is undefined this gives in below mentioned line >>>CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(),
                    jArrayCategoryWise);

Answer (score 0):

First, change your adapter to expends the

```
extends ArrayAdapter<String>
```

Change the constructor:
    public CustomGrid(Context c) {
           super(c, R.layout.fragment_pizza);
        }
Now Change `getView()` method:

```
// Get the item
        String item = getItem(position);
```

Set this item text to your view and if you require more data sets, create the model class and change
`extends ArrayAdapter<String>` with `extends ArrayAdapter<ModelClass>`
and

```
 // Get the item
            ModelClass item = getItem(position);
```

Now in your Activity class, initilize the ModelClass, set it's variables and add to the adapter using add or addAll methods.

Comment: what is the change i should do to String[] ImageURL = new String[responseJson.length()];