# Android grid view of images consumes all memory and crashes

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am trying to debug where in the my app I am consuming all memory and causing the app to crash.

It all loads up find but as I scroll down the grid view I load more images to the GridView all ok. If I scroll back up I can see they are being loaded from the cache. But as I keep scrolling down the device allocates around 250mb and crashes. Any ideas where I am going wrong.

I should also probably note that this Gird has around 150 images (~20kb each) on when it crashes. I was hoping to get more.

Please be gentle on me, I am new to Java and Android.

ItemAdapter

```
public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.itemList = objects;

    final int maxMemory = (int)(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
    imageCache = new LruCache<>(cacheSize);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_staggered_grid_view_item, parent, false);

    //Display item name in textview widget
    Item item = itemList.get(position);
    TextView item_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    item_title.setText(item.getTitle());

    TextView item_brand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    item_brand.setText(item.getBrand());

    //display image
    Bitmap bitmap = imageCache.get(item.getItemId());
    if (bitmap != null) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        ItemAndView container = new ItemAndView();
        container.item = item;
        container.view = view;

        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
        loader.execute(container);
    }

    return view;
}

class ItemAndView {
    public Item item;
    public View view;
    public Bitmap bitmap;
}

private class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<ItemAndView, Void, ItemAndView> {

    @Override
    protected ItemAndView doInBackground(ItemAndView... params) {
        ItemAndView container = params[0];
        Item item = container.item;

        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(FeedFragment.IMAGES_BASE_URL);
            sb.append(item.getCategory());
            sb.append("/");
            sb.append(item.getProductId());
            sb.append("/img1.jpg");
            String imageUrl = sb.toString();

            InputStream in = (InputStream) new URL(imageUrl).getContent();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            item.setBitmap(bitmap);
            in.close();
            container.bitmap = bitmap;
            return container;
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ItemAndView itemAndView) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) itemAndView.view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageBitmap(itemAndView.bitmap);
        if (imageCache.get(itemAndView.item.getItemId()) == null) {
            imageCache.put(itemAndView.item.getItemId(), itemAndView.bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

FeedFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (feedItemList == null) {
        requestData(FEED_BASE_URL + pageNum);
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_staggered_grid_view, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (feedItemList != null) {
        updateDisplay();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

private void requestData(String uri) {
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
    task.execute(uri);
    pageNum++;
}

protected void updateDisplay() {
    feedAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.feed_staggered_grid_view_item, feedItemList);
    feedGridView = (StaggeredGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    feedGridView.setAdapter(feedAdapter);
    feedGridView.setOnScrollListener(this);
    feedGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (!isLoading && totalItemCount != 0) {
        int lastItemInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if (lastItemInScreen >= totalItemCount) {
            isLoading = true;
            requestData(FEED_BASE_URL + pageNum);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Item item = feedItemList.get(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getSherlockActivity(), ItemViewer.class);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("item_title", item.getTitle());
    extras.putString("item_description", item.getDescription());
    extras.putString("item_brand", item.getBrand());
    extras.putDouble("item_price", item.getPrice());
    extras.putString("item_photo", item.getPhoto());
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    startActivity(intent);
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Item>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Item> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        List<Item> data = ItemFeedJSONParser.parseFeed(content);
        if (feedItemList == null) {
            feedItemList = data;
        } else {
            feedItemList.addAll(data);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Item> result) {
        if (pageNum <= 1) {
            updateDisplay();
        } else {
            feedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        isLoading = false;

    }
}
```

And here is the error message

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
Process: com.test.game.test, PID: 10931
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 429212 byte allocation with 80604 free bytes and 78KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:649)
        at com.test.game.adapters.ItemAdapter$ImageLoader.doInBackground(ItemAdapter.java:106)
        at com.test.game.adapters.ItemAdapter$ImageLoader.doInBackground(ItemAdapter.java:89)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: You are loading them too fast, try adding some time between starting too many image loading procedures. Please note that this code that you supplied starts loading them ALL AT ONCE.

Comment: @user968808 check this out .. it may help for adapter class http://stackoverflow.com/a/28166616/1140237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're loading a bitmap that is too big. Not only the download of the image but the placement should also be done in the background. Use an AsyncTask to do that or you can always use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion). I have had the same problem and solved it by using Ion, works very well.

Furthermore, do not load one different view for every item, use the convertView.

Comment: Thanks ill try Ion. Is a 20kb image too big? What size should I be aiming for?

Comment: Glad to have helped. There's not a fixed perfect size for images, because it depends on how much you're loading. Anyway you shouldn't make the user pay for this loadings making the device slow while they are being loaded. So you should manage them in a way that they get loaded in the background and slowly (not all at a time) and those libraries do that for ya :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating *view* for every call, try using *convertView*. Try the following code for the first two lines of your code in *getView*:

```
View view;
if (convertView==null){
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_staggered_grid_view_item, parent, false);
}else{
   view = convertView;
}
```

Comment: This helps to a certain extent. As in, I can see the memory actually being reduced a few times, but still crashes with the same error and causes strange behaviour on the grid with the images changing as I scroll down. I have added the Fragment class in case that helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go to mainfiest file and add the below line on your application tag:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: no, avoid this. This option (according to Google) should be your last resort. A larger heap will generate longer GC.