# Unable to link tableRow elements to Table Layout

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android app development. Please help me in resolving this issue

**Issue :** 
I've created a table Layout programmatically in the onCreate() and the contents that are to be shown in the table are fetched from a remote source for which I've used AsyncTask to perform all the data fetching and processing part in the background. Now, there is loop which picks up data to show on the screen. So, whenever the loop come across the data part that is to be shown on the screen, I've used

```
textViews.addElement((TextView) propertyInfo.getValue());
                            textViews.lastElement().setText(textViews.lastElement().toString());
                            tableRow.addView(textViews.lastElement());
```

> In the onPostExecute(). and on onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_allocation__details);


       TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                                                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tableLayout.setScrollContainer(hasWindowFocus());
        tableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tableLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_material_dark);


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Allocation_Details.this);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        new SoapAccessTask().execute();

    }
```

Here, I don't know how to add table rows to the table layout which is in onCreate()

> **Note**: I want to do it programmatically.

Please help to do it properly if I'm doing it wrong

Comment: hello pavan do you want to show data as a listing like vertically ?

Comment: @user1140237 yes, I want to show it in a list (vertically) in 2 columns

Comment: so is there any specific reason not to use GridView Or recyclerview ?

Comment: No, I just wanted to show it in a table so I just started with table layout. Didn't think of using GridView or recycleview.

Comment: if its easy and preferable way to do it. Please help me to do it that way.

Comment: thn i would suggest you to use GridView or recyclerview with adapter because by using that it will not have any perfomance issue , resuability of view can be maintain easily. check this link if you need to know anything about grid http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html]

Comment: the table should be dynamic as the amount of data to shown might sometimes be more or sometimes less

Comment: Yes for  that please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28166616/1140237 and above link  `CustomGrid ` is the adapter where you can found adapter related things